# string to char* conversion

Tags: c++, string

I am in a code base where there are lots of function calls to functions that take a pointer as an argument.  However, the function call passes a "string" object as if it's pointer.  The following code is shown to give you an idea.

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void dum(char *s) {
    printf("%s\n", s);
}

operator char* (string s) {
    return s.c_str();
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    string st("Hello world");
    dum(st);
    return 0;
}
```

I am not allowed to change the syntax for all these functions or function calls. One possible solution I came up is to add a operator overload, but unfortunately it doesn't work, here is the error from g++ (ver 4.7.3), command line: `g++ -std=c++11 te2.cc`

```
error: ‘operator char*(std::string)’ must be a nonstatic member function
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

**UPDATE1**

@ferruccio's answer reminded me to mention that there are function calls like

```
dum(dum2());
```

where dum2() is a function is like:

```
string dum2() {
    string s;
    //.....
    return s;
}
```

So the wrapper like the following doesn't work (), compiler gives error `no matching function for call to ‘dum(std::string)’`

```
void dum(string &s) {
    dum(s.c_str());
}
```

Comment: Can you pass the st.c_str() to those functions calls, like dum(st.c_str())?

Comment: This will work if I am allowed to change the function call.  There are `dum(st)` like of function calls all over the place.  Wish there is a easy way to take care of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a simple function overload for each function that takes a `char*`. e.g.

```
void dum(const string& s) {
    dum(s.c_str());
}
```

Comment: that's a good idea,  forget to mention that are functions like `dum(dum2());` for some function `string dum2() { string s; .... ;  return s; }`

Comment: your answer is closed to solved my problem, I just removed the "&" in your solution and added it all over my code and it worked (I didn't observe the rule imposed on me not to change other code, since this seems to be the only way to get it working). Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
operator char* (string s) {
    return s.c_str();
}
```

This is broken (if it was allowed). When this function returns, `s` no longer exists. So a pointer to its contents is of no use.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.  Yes `s` doesn't exist when it returns, but the memory that hold the data is still there, isn't it?

Comment: @codingFun Maybe by luck or accident. But you can't rely on it.